# Graphing routines in Tcl/Tk

Tags: tcl, gnuplot, tk-toolkit, graphing

I want to do simple graphing routines in Tcl/Tk like scatter plot, x-y plot, histograms. I am using Tcl/Tk 8.5.7. I found in Tcler's wiki that there are few options such as [BLT](http://wiki.tcl.tk/199) which is not supported in Tcl/Tk 8.5+

Is there any Tcl/Tk interface to `gnuplot` or any widget to accomplish graphing?

Please let me know about the choices for graphing routines in Tcl/Tk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnuplot can indeed produce output that Tcl/Tk can consume. [This page on the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13555_) describes how (though with some extra complexity because it is doing animations). Here's a simplified version:

```
package require Tk
eval [exec gnuplot << "
    set term tk
    plot x*x
"]
pack [canvas .c]
gnuplot .c
```

The `gnuplot` command is created by `eval`uating the output that the gnuplot *program* produced. This is a little bit tricky, especially if you're wanting to do multiple plots (hint: use namespaces) but it is pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the simple tklib plotchart package for some simpler things. 
http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/plotchart.html