# Plotting with Gnuplot in Tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have seen a topic regarding to how we plot graphs with Gnuplot in Tk Canvas. Here are the simple code sample from Donal Fellows@Donal Fellows. Can someone help me on these two commands in Bold(set term tk;gnuplot .c)? I can not understand what does it mean.Thanks.

```
 package require Tk
eval [exec gnuplot << "
    **set term tk**
    plot x*x
"]
pack [canvas .c]
**gnuplot .c**
```

Comment: Reference post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9080543/1578604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the *gnuplot* program with the terminal set to `tk`, it writes to its standard output a Tcl script that will create a procedure. That procedure is called `gnuplot`, and it takes a single argument which is the name of the canvas to plot onto. So we call the *gnuplot* program with the appropriate arguments to get it to tell you how to make a command that will actually do the plotting. We `eval` that result, make the canvas, and delegate to that newly-created `gnuplot` command the actual plotting on the canvas.

It's a little odd, and theoretically unsafe (what if the *gnuplot* is hacked?!?!?! Oh noes!) but actually works quite well in practice.

---

To see why it works, try doing:

```
puts [exec gnuplot << "
    set term tk
    plot x*x
"]
```

Instead of evaluating the code, that will print it out. You'll see that it's a procedure definition, and how exactly it all works. (Alas, I've not got gnuplot installed on this computer at the moment, so I can't do the check quite instantly for you…)

Comment: Over here, it works as you say. The output is quite long and repetitive, not worth posting here, I presume. In short, it defines 2 one-liner proc's: `proc gnuplot_plotarea {}` and `proc gnuplot_axisranges {}`. And a third `proc gnuplot can` with 500+ lines of code drawing lines, writing text, and so on, on the `can`canvas (`$can create line  ...`, `eval $can create text...`, ...)

Comment: I realized that Donal's suggestion works if gnuplot 5.0.6 is used but the same code throws an error when 5.2.2 is used:            line 0: Error re-writing output file: Invalid argument

    while executing
"exec gnuplot << "
     set term tk
     plot x*x""
    invoked from within
"eval [exec gnuplot << "
     set term tk
     plot x*x"
     ]"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of *gnuplot*, but as far as understand the 2 command are very simple.

```
set term tk
```

Assign the value string *tk* to the variable *term*.

```
gnuplot .c
```

Launch the command *gnuplot* with argument *.c*.

In your code the *.c* is just the name of the tk *canvas* widget.

More intriguing is the first **[exec gnuplot <<...]** that execute an external command called *gnuplot* that initialize the *tk* script and define the *tk* command *gnuplot* used to draw the plot on a canvas.

It looks like the external *gnuplot* command generate the tck code to define all what is needed.